# ¿como eliminar margenes de bootstrap solo en el caroufredsel?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap

```css
@font-face {
    font-family: "champagne&limousines";
    src: url('../fonts/Guava/Champagne & Limousines.ttf') format('truetype'); 

    font-family: "champagne&limousines-bold";
    src: url('../fonts/Guava/Champagne & Limousines Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
} 

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font: 14px "champagne&limousines", sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
/*revisar logo*/
a.navbar-brand {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    background: url(../img/logo/logotrans.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    width: 114px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a 
{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

a.menu-lindo {
    font: 26px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

a.menu-lindo:hover, a.menu-lindo:focus {
    font: 26px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
    border-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #fff;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #b71c1c;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #D32F2F;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    border-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
}

.jumbotron {
    padding: 15px 30px !important;
}

.well {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

a {
    color: #D32F2F;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #b71c1c;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
    color: #D32F2F;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 .titulo-receta {
    margin-top: 170px;
}

.miimagen{
    margin-top: 80px;
}

a.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
}

a.btn:hover, a.btn:focus, a.btn:active, a.btn:visited {
    color: #fff !important;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
}

.backbar {
    margin-top: 55px;
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 0.7);
}

.backbar .btn {
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 0.7);
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.backbar .btn:hover, .backbar .btn:focus {
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 1);
}

/*slider*/
.slider  {
    margin-top: 55px
}

.container .body-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.slider .slider-carousel {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.caroufredsel_wraper {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.slider, .slider ul.slider-carousel, .slider ul.slider-carousel li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li h3 {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.img1 {
    background: url('../img/slider/1.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img2 {
    background: url('../img/slider/2.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
    background: url('../img/slider/3.png');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li.selected a {
    color: #E74C3C;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li a {
    color: #34495E;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li {
    padding: 0 3px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}


/*footer */
footer .copyright {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
    <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
        <li class="img1">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li class="img2">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li class="img3">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sliderpager">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

quiero eliminar los margenes de modo que las imágenes del slider abarquen todo el ancho de la pagina, pero solo de la parte del slider, lo demas esta perfecto...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Lo que tienes que hacer es usar el selector universal para eleminar el margen y el padding en todos los elementos de la siguiente manera, además de hacer que el borde y el padding cuenten para medir el tamaño de los elementos:

```
* {margin:0;padding:0;box-sizing:border-box;}
```

Una vez hecho esto ya añades el margen y el padding a lo que quieras, pero que de base ambos sean 0, además viendo tu código esto te ahorrará mucho tiempo y líneas de código, he visto que a muchos elementos les quitas el margen manualmente y usando el selector universal no perderás tiempo en hacer eso.

Aquí tienes tu ejemplo con lo que te he indicado:

```css
* {
  margin:0;
  padding:0;
  box-sizing:border-box;
}

@font-face {
    font-family: "champagne&limousines";
    src: url('../fonts/Guava/Champagne & Limousines.ttf') format('truetype'); 

    font-family: "champagne&limousines-bold";
    src: url('../fonts/Guava/Champagne & Limousines Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
} 

body {
    padding-top: 50px;
    padding-bottom: 20px;
    font: 14px "champagne&limousines", sans-serif;
    text-align: justify;
}

/* Set padding to keep content from hitting the edges */
.body-content {
    padding-left: 0px;
    padding-right: 0px;
}

/* Override the default bootstrap behavior where horizontal description lists 
   will truncate terms that are too long to fit in the left column 
*/
.dl-horizontal dt {
    white-space: normal;
}

/* Set width on the form input elements since they're 100% wide by default */
input,
select,
textarea {
    max-width: 280px;
}
/*revisar logo*/
a.navbar-brand {
    background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
    background: url(../img/logo/logotrans.png) no-repeat top left;
    display: block;
    width: 114px;
    height: 64px;
    margin: 20px 20px;
    margin-right: 40px;
    text-indent: -9999px; /* hides the link text */
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-nav > li > a 
{
    color: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.7);
}

a.menu-lindo {
    font: 26px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    margin-top: 25px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    line-height: 25px;
}

a.menu-lindo:hover, a.menu-lindo:focus {
    font: 26px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

.navbar {
    background-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
    border-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle {
    border-color: #fff;
    border-top-color: #fff;
    border-right-color: #fff;
    border-bottom-color: #fff;
    border-left-color: #fff;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:hover {
    background-color: #b71c1c;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-toggle:focus {
    background-color: #D32F2F;
}

.navbar-inverse .navbar-collapse, .navbar-inverse .navbar-form {
    border-color: rgba(211,47,47, 0.9);
}

.jumbotron {
    padding: 15px 30px !important;
}

.well {
    margin-top: 80px;
}

a {
    color: #D32F2F;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    font-size: 18px;
}

a:hover {
    color: #b71c1c;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

a:focus {
    color: #D32F2F;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
    text-decoration: none;
}

h2 .titulo-receta {
    margin-top: 170px;
}

.miimagen{
    margin-top: 80px;
}

a.btn {
    color: #fff;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
}

a.btn:hover, a.btn:focus, a.btn:active, a.btn:visited {
    color: #fff !important;
    font: 18px "champagne&limousines-bold", sans-serif;
}

.backbar {
    margin-top: 55px;
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 0.7);
}

.backbar .btn {
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 0.7);
    margin: 10px 10px;
    border-color: #fff;
}

.backbar .btn:hover, .backbar .btn:focus {
    background: rgba(118,129,159, 1);
}

/*slider*/
.slider  {
    margin-top: 55px
}

.container .body-content {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.slider .slider-carousel {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    box-sizing: content-box;
}

.caroufredsel_wraper {
    margin-left: 0;
    margin-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
    padding-right: 0;
}

.slider, .slider ul.slider-carousel, .slider ul.slider-carousel li {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li h3 {
    margin-top: 150px;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    color: #FFF;
}

.slider ul.slider-carousel li p {
    margin-bottom: 20px;
}

.img1 {
    background: url('https://misanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/pantera.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img2 {
    background: url('https://misanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/pantera.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.img3 {
    background: url('https://misanimales.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/11/pantera.jpg');
    background-size: 100% 100%;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li.selected a {
    color: #E74C3C;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li a {
    color: #34495E;
}

.slider ul.sliderpager li {
    padding: 0 3px;
    height: 28px;
    line-height: 28px;
    display: inline-block;
}


/*footer */
footer .copyright {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 80px;
}
```

```html
<div class="slider" id="slider">
    <ul class="slider-carousel" id="slider-carousel">
        <li class="img1">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li class="img2">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
        <li class="img3">
            <h3></h3>
            <p></p>
        </li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="sliderpager">
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-circle"></i></a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: gracias!! pude sobrescribir todo :)

Comment: De nada, un placer haberte ayudado, si te ha servido para corregir tu problema marca la respuesta como correcta para que esta pregunta sea considerada solucionada.